# Remove NFT from a Collection

Tags: solana, metaplex

Say i have an NFT generated from CandyMachine. Candy Machine will automatically set a Collection to the NFTs. I want to remove a specific NFT from that collection. I don't want it to be transferred to other NFT collection. I just want to remove its collection  [attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW6pN.jpg)

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible to remove a NFT from a collection.

You can use the [unverify](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#unverify-the-collection) instruction for it. This will set the verified to false and with this basically remove it from collection. It will not remove the key string from metadata, but that should not be an issue since a NFT is only part of a collection if verified is true. To remove any traces in the metadata you could also use the [set and verify](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#set-and-verify-the-collection) instruction to set a different collection value.

Easiest method to do this is using [metaboss](https://metaboss.rs):

```
metaboss collections unverify [FLAGS] [OPTIONS] --collection-mint <collection-mint> --nft-mint <nft-mint>
```

If you want to replace the collection use

```
metaboss collections set-and-verify [FLAGS] [OPTIONS] --collection-mint <collection-mint> --nft-mint <nft-mint> --update-authority-nft <update-authority-nft>
```

Comment: hi Mark thanks for the ideas.. , i'm able to set the verified to false (also in the post's screenshot), my problem with that still existing in metadata (even if it's unverified) is because opensea is still showing that NFT from the collection. unless if i really set it to a different collection. - that would solve that problem.. 
but what i really like to happen is to really remove the "collection" from metadata. - that's what i'd like to ask if that's possible.

Comment: There is no "remove" instruction unfortunately. You could only replace it. The problem is different though i think: OpenSea has to pull and ingest, that the NFT is not part of the collection anymore - You should contact their support and ask them to refresh the collection data.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you for clarifying and confirming it!